# Javascript callbacks for two separate functions and outputting in same place

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have the following code:

```
    displayOrders: function(){
    function getRetailerName(retailerID, callback){
        var retailerName;
        db.transaction(function(qry){
            qry.executeSql("SELECT retailerName FROM retailers WHERE token = '"+retailerID+"' ", [], function(tx, results1){
                var len1 = results1.rows.length;
                var retailerName;
                for (var i1=0; i1<len1; i1++){
                    retailerName = results1.rows.item(i1).retailerName;
                    callback(retailerName);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    db.transaction(function(qry){
        qry.executeSql("SELECT * FROM orders", [], function(tx, results){
            //query was a success
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var orderTime = results.rows.item(i).orderTime;

                var retailerName;
                getRetailerName(results.rows.item(i).retailerID,function(name) { //this uses a callback function... need to because request to DB is a
                    retailerName = name ;
                    $('#orderHistoryCollapsible').append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h3>'+retailerName+' - '+orderTime+'</h3><p>Im the collapsible set content for section 1.</p></div>');
                    $(".orderHistoryCollapsible").collapsibleset();
                    $(".orderHistoryCollapsible").collapsibleset('refresh');            
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

So basically the code runs two separate database queries and retrieves data to be put into a listview. The getRetailerName function provides a callback which is used in the query below, which adds both sets of data to the 'orderHistoryCollapsible' div.

My problem is that the orderTime value that is also meant to be inserted into the DOM is returning the last value in the loop each time. Its almost as if the both queries need to be provided as callbacks? But then I am not sure how I would append the data to the right place..

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have never seen SQL in Javascript code. If this is a common DBMS like MySQL, Oracle, ..., you should consider using an SQL join to improve performance. You can reduce all the selects to just one and then loop over this single result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var orderTime` in your code might be misleading, since in javascript the scope of local variables is limited not to their enclosing blocks (like in Java), but instead to their enclosing functions. More specifically, your `orderTime` is initialized once, then overwritten in each loop iteration (i.e. it is the same variable every time).

The callback function references that variable (which is called a closure, meaning that the variable will exist after the function where it was defined has exited - because the callback function has a reference to it). By the time the callback is invoked, the loop has finished its execution, so the `orderTime` has its last value.

The following should work:

```
displayOrders: function(){
    function getRetailerName(retailerID, callback){
        var retailerName;
        db.transaction(function(qry){
            qry.executeSql("SELECT retailerName FROM retailers WHERE token = '"+retailerID+"' ", [], function(tx, results1){
                var len1 = results1.rows.length;
                var retailerName;
                for (var i1=0; i1<len1; i1++){
                    retailerName = results1.rows.item(i1).retailerName;
                    callback(retailerName);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function callbackFn(orderTime) {
        return function(name) {
                $('#orderHistoryCollapsible').append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h3>'+name+' - '+orderTime+'</h3><p>Im the collapsible set content for section 1.</p></div>');
                $(".orderHistoryCollapsible").collapsibleset();
                $(".orderHistoryCollapsible").collapsibleset('refresh');    
        };
    }

    db.transaction(function(qry){
        qry.executeSql("SELECT * FROM orders", [], function(tx, results){
            //query was a success
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var orderTime = results.rows.item(i).orderTime;
                getRetailerName(results.rows.item(i).retailerID, callbackFn(orderTime));
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `orderTime` is in the function scope (`function(tx, results)`) and not in the loop scope. This means, that when it is captured in the closure of `function(name)`, there is only one instance. And when the loop finishes it will have the value of the last call.

You can fix this, if you enclose the loop body in an anonymous function

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    function() {
        var orderTime = results.rows.item(i).orderTime;

        var retailerName;
        getRetailerName(results.rows.item(i).retailerID,function(name) { //this uses a callback function... need to because request to DB is a
            retailerName = name ;
            $('#orderHistoryCollapsible').append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"><h3>'+retailerName+' - '+orderTime+'</h3><p>Im the collapsible set content for section 1.</p></div>');
            $(".orderHistoryCollapsible").collapsibleset();
            $(".orderHistoryCollapsible").collapsibleset('refresh');            
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you have a new scope every time the body is run and thus a new instance of `orderTime`.